# AG-Grid (Enterprise) Column Menu Listener

Tags: javascript, angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

Is there a way to set a listener to column-menu, so that an event is fired when I open and close the menu?

Feature description: https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-column-menu/

I already searched in the official documentation, but didn't find an answer.

Background is:
I want to store the table state with displayed cols, sorting, position of cols, filter etc. in a database. Of course I could use the listeners like `onFilterChanged`, `onDisplayedColumnsChanged` or `onSortChanged`. 
Problem is, that it will be fired every time when something changes and so there are produced a lot of unwanted api-calls.

Thats why I want to perform **one** call when the column-menu is closed.

---

> ### Update
>
> As Viqas said in his [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56750477/5142496), there is no official way to do it. I
>   tried to avoid the solution with `postProcessPopup` and tried to find a cleaner
>   solution for my problem - to store the table state.
>
> For a workaround with a callback when ColumnMenu is closed [Viqas Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56750477/5142496) is more appropriate.
>
> **Notice that this is no workaround for the callback itself - it is just a (possible) solution to store the table state and perform ONE API Call**
>
> I used the `ngOnDestory()` function of Angular.

```html
ngOnDestory(): void {
  const tableState = {
    columnState: this.gridOptions.columnApi.getColumnState(),
    columnGroupState: this.gridOptions.columnApi.getColumnGroupState(),
    sortState: this.gridOptions.api.getSortModel(),
    filterState: this.gridOptions.api.getFilterModel(),
    displayedColumns: this.gridOptions.columnApi.getAllDisplayedColumns()
  };

  // submit it to API
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right, there's no official way to do it. A workaround could be to detect when the menu is closed yourself. Ag-grid does provide you the `postProcessPopup` callback (see [here](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-column-menu/#repositioning-the-popup)) which provides the parameter of type `PostProcessPopupParams`; this contains the column menu popup element that is displayed, so you could check when the menu is no longer visible.

Create a variable to store the columnMenu element in:

```
columnMenu: any = null;
```

Store the columnMenu in this variable using the ag-grid event `postProcessPopup`:

```
<ag-grid-angular [postProcessPopup]="postProcessPopup"></ag-grid-angular>

this.postProcessPopup = function(params) {
  this.columnMenu = params.ePopup;
}.bind(this);
```

Then create a listener to detect when the column menu is no longer visible in the dom:

```
this.renderer.listen('window', 'click',(e:Event)=>{
      console.log(this.columnMenu)
        const columnMenuIsInDom = document.body.contains(this.columnMenu);

        if (!columnMenuIsInDom && this.columnMenu != null)
        {
          this.columnMenu = null;
        }
    });
```

This is slightly hacky and a workaround, but I can't think of a better way at the moment.

Take a look at [this](https://plnkr.co/edit/B52A4m8gj68wxGK6dzHJ?p=preview) Plunker for illustration.